# replace csv values with lookup to another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a tag field which has values like:

```
table1
______
data1, data2, data3
```

I have a second table that maps id's to each piece of data like:

```
table2
_________
id | info
1  | data1
2  | data2
3  | data3
```

etc...

I want to do a lookup/replace in table1 such that the tags field now contains the comma separated id's from table2 like this:

```
table1
______
1,2,3
```

My mysql is rusty.  I was thinking something like this:

```
   UPDATE table1   
   SET tags = REPLACE(tags, '', '')
   WHERE tags LIKE ???
```

But could use some help filling in the blanks.  Is there any way to accomplish this?
Might be worth noting, unfortunately not every item in t1 tags will have a matching entry in t2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really only have one row in `table1`?

In any case, you can do what you want by re-constructing the id string:

```
update table1
    set tags = (select group_concat(t2.id)
                from t2
                where find_in_set(t2.info, t1.tags) > 0
               )
```

If you want the order to be the same as for the original tags:

```
update table1
    set tags = (select group_concat(t2.id order by find_in_set(t2.info, t1.tags))
                from t2
                where find_in_set(t2.info, t1.tags) > 0
               )
```

Comment: hmm.  this doesn't appear to be working as I'm only seeing one value in the updated field, and the others are empty.  I should have mentioned that if there is no match in t2, ideally i'd like to keep the existing value in the t1 tag field.

Comment: @jco . . . That actually changes the structure of the problem.  If you really need to do that, I would suggest that you change the structure of the database to have the tags on separate rows instead of in a comma-delimited list.  Such lists are usually an indication of poor database structure.  In other words, this answer is a hack to get around poor database design, but you don't want to take it too far.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand your point.  Since the list wasn't too large I was planning on "cleaning up" the non-matches, as I am at the beginning of a new project.  Thanks for the help!